# How to add text or label in dataframe style to display the information

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have below style to show the difference of two dataframe, and additionally How do i display total number of records and number of mismatch rows using dataframe/pandas style?

```
       def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
            attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
            other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)
            return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                                index=data.index, columns=data.columns)
        caption_styles = {
            'selector':'caption',
            'props':[('font-weight', 'bold'),('margin-bottom','25px'),('font-size','25px')]
        }
        select_styles = {  # for row hover use <tr> instead of <td>
            'selector': '',
            'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse'),('margin', '100px auto')]
        }
        
        table_styles = {  # for row hover use <tr> instead of <td>
            'selector': 'table',
            'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse'),('margin', '100px auto')]
        }
        
        tbody_styles = {  # for row hover use <tr> instead of <td>
            'selector': 'tbody',
            'props': [('border', '1px solid #A2DBFA')]
        }
        td_styles = {  # for row hover use <tr> instead of <td>
            'selector': 'td',
            'props': [('border', '1px solid #A2DBFA'),('padding','1em'),('border-bottom','2px solid #A2DBFA')]
        }
        th_styles = {  # for row hover use <tr> instead of <td>
            'selector': 'th',
            'props': [('border', '1px solid #A2DBFA'),('padding','1em'),('background-color','#39A2DB'),('border-bottom','2px solid #A2DBFA')]
        }
df_all = pd.concat([df_source.set_index('id'), df_target.set_index('id')], 
                   axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second']).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df_source.columns[1:]]
        df_out = df_final.style.set_table_styles([caption_styles,select_styles,table_styles, tbody_styles,td_styles, th_styles]).set_caption("Test Case 1").apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
```

once i have all the data, i will be rendering using `df.render()` and will be writing as Html.
I want to display the total number of records and number of mismatch rows using pandas/dataframe style(mentioned in red text)

[image]

Comment: show a sample of your original dataset(s) (preferrably as text or CSV, not image) and the logic you use to detect the mismatch. better to explain the logic in english than the logic in code.

Comment: @Joshua here the ask is not about how i need to achieve mismatch(which is already done) and what i need is -to show the number of mismatch records and total records in the style i have already posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

#### a) (simplest) incorporate the information into the caption, and insert the calculated values:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["Unit 1", "Unit 2"], ["Some Value", "Another"]], names=["Dept", "Workflow"]),
                  columns=["Comment 1", "Comment 2"],
                  data=[["Green", "Red"], ["Yellow", "Yellow"], ["Green", "Red"], ["Yellow", "Yellow"]])
styler = df.style
styler.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'td', 'props': 'text-align: left;'},
                         {'selector': 'th.level1', 'props': 'text-align: left;'},
                         {'selector': 'caption', 'props': 'color: red;'}])\
      .applymap(lambda x: f"color: {x.lower()}")\
      .set_caption(f"number of reds: {2}<br>number of rows: {4}")
```

[image]

Since the caption is rendered directly as HTML from string you can actually be clever and use the caption to build multiple elements. For example:

```py
styler.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'td', 'props': 'text-align: left;'},
                         {'selector': 'th.level1', 'props': 'text-align: left;'},
                         {'selector': 'caption', 'props': 'color: red;'},
                         {'selector': '.my-cls', 'props': 'color: blue; font-size: 16pt;'])\
      .applymap(lambda x: f"color: {x.lower()}")\
      .set_caption('<span class="my-cls">Big Blue Text</span><br>little red text')
```

[image]

#### b) (harder) Subclass the styler template as explained in the user guide

Create a new file, "my_html.tpl" in the same directory as your notebook as follows:

```
{% extends "html_table.tpl" %}
{% block table %}
<h1>{{ table_title|default("My Table") }}</h1>
<p style="color: red; font-size: 1.5em;">number of reds: {{ reds }}<br>number of rows: {{ rows }}</p>
{{ super() }}
{% endblock table %}
```

Then create your own `Styler`

```py
from pandas.io.formats.style import Styler
MyStyler = Styler.from_custom_template(searchpath="", html_table="my_table.tpl")
styler = MyStyler(df)
styler.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'td', 'props': 'text-align: left;'},
                         {'selector': 'th.level1', 'props': 'text-align: left;'}])\
      .applymap(lambda x: f"color: {x.lower()}")\
      .render(reds=2, rows=4)
```

[image]